# Woocommerce Coupons - can't update product ids using update_post_meta programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to programmatically create a Woocommerce coupon when a form is submitted  on a single page template using the ACF fields from my page template ID for the coupon properties.

Looking at the Woocommerce [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/) on how to do this, they suggest setting the properties using the `update_post_meta()` after inserting a new coupon.

However, when doing this the product ids aren't being aded when printing out the `WC_Coupon` object for the generated coupon and returns an empty array.

I've made sure the ACF field `landing_page_products` returns an array of ids when printing this out separately but for some reason doesn't get added to the object or displays in the admin coupon screen.

I discovered that if i use the `$coupon->set_product_ids($products);` instead of updating the meta then this seems to work.

Can anyone explain why the update meta for the product ids isn't working?

```
$coupon = [
            'post_title' => $coupon_code,
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
        ];

        $coupon_id = wp_insert_post($coupon);

        // Get products meta from current landing page $post_id // 
        $products = get_field('landing_page_products', $post_id);

        /** Set default coupon meta **/
        update_post_meta($coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes');
        update_post_meta($coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'no' );
        update_post_meta($coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );
        update_post_meta($coupon_id, 'product_ids', $products );


WC_Coupon Object
(
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
    [product_ids] => Array
                    (
                    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked on Creating and Updating Woocommerce coupons programmatically before, using: [Woo Docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjgueS4-5PkAhVC_qQKHeNDBjkQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.woocommerce.com%2Fdocument%2Fcreate-a-coupon-programatically%2F&usg=AOvVaw3zA7tWO700gtH-LRLdhbRB) - *Despite this doc, array() parameter for update_post_meta is not working.*

This is my code (tested) working now, the 'product_ids' for update_post_meta **requires string, not an array**. Example code for products with IDs: 130 and 131:

```
    update_post_meta( $_newCouponID, 'product_ids', "130, 131");

    //or

    $product_ids = "130, 131";
    update_post_meta( $_newCouponID, 'product_ids', $product_ids);

    //still use wp_update_post at the end of your code
    wp_update_post($_newCouponID);
```

I hope this helps. Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you, the other post meta seems to update without a problem. It just seems to be the product ids which don't get updated. I've tried adding the wp_update_post like you suggested but it still hasn't worked. I might just have to stick with using the $coupon->set_product_ids() instead. Just frustrating that Woocommerce say this works when it doesn't.

Comment: Solved the issue, I edited my answer you may check it.

Comment: Yes! That's worked :) Wonder why the product_ids are stored as a string and not an array like the product_categories

Comment: I am wondering that too :) I checked the database row, when an array assigned to 'product_ids' like in coupon e-mail restriction (which works with array), it does not work. Then I simply enter "130, 131" and it worked.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I needed to do updates after the post is saved. The hook I used was wp_after_insert_post. save_post didn't work for me. Hopefully helps someone who gets into similar issue.